# Does a string concatenation allocate new strings in memory for each string in the chain or only for the string being changed?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

```
//will need these in a second
string a = "5";
string b = "7";
string c = "3";
```

So because C# will allocate more strings in memory

```
string mystring = "";
mystring += a;
mystring += b;
mystring += c;
```

is going to be slower than

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(a).Append(b).Append(c);
```

So then, what about:

```
string mystring = "";
mystring += a + b + c;
```

Is it just the `+=` part that is slow, or is `+` also a culprit here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+= is sintax sugare for s +a.

What about performance, on big numbers of strings StringBuilder is much much more performant.

Comment: OH YEAH! I should have remembered that.

Comment: Ok, so what a question? :) on small numbers I never measured, also cause the range of time is too small and can not be relevant.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I know enough now to make a good enough decision, not like I'm writing code for airplanes. I have to give this one to you because of the facepalm you inspired.

Comment: I don't understand this answer very well, but I'm pretty sure it's wrong.

Comment: @gabe you can not do not understand the aswer and downvote on it. Explain your opinion.

Comment: You seem to be saying that `+=` is just syntactic sugar for `+`, which implies that the first example (with 3 `+=`) will perform the same as the last example (with 1 `+=` and 2 `+`). In fact the last example will perform better than the first (and the second).

Comment: Ok, obviously not.  I mean that a+=b is the same like a+b. The fact that making more assignment calls makes things worse seemed obviouse to me.

Comment: To be clear: `a += b;` is syntactic sugar for `a = a + b;`. It's not specific for strings, it works the same for any type that implements the `+` operator.

Comment: You should state exactly what you think is obvious, because I really don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
mystring += "5" + "7" + "3";
```

will actually compile into the same as:

```
mystring = String.Concat(mystring, "573");
```

When you concatenate literal strings, the compiler will do that for you at compile time.

If you use string variables instead:

```
string mystring = "";
string str1 = "5";
string str2 = "7";
string str3 = "3";
mystring += str1 + str2 + str3;
```

The last line will compile into the same as:

```
mystring = String.Concat(myString, str1, str2, str3);
```

As you send all the strings into the `Concat` method, it can create the resulting string in one go. What it does is quite similar to using `StringBuilder` to create the string.

Comment: I thought Concat had the same performance as +? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260972(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Ryan: Using the `+` operator on strings are converted into calls to `String.Concat` by the compiler, so it's not only the performance that is the same, the resulting code is identical. :)

Comment: Oh I see what you meant now :)

Answer (score 1):

The following will make 3 memory allocations *and* copy the data multiple times:

```
string mystring = "";
mystring += a; // allocate string; copy a
mystring += b; // allocate string; copy a and b
mystring += c; // allocate string; copy a, b, and c
```

This will probably make 2 memory allocations and copy the data twice:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // make 1 allocation for all the strings
sb.Append(a).Append(b).Append(c); // copy a, b, and c
string mystring = sb.ToString();  // make another allocation; copy a, b, and c
```

This will make just 1 memory allocation and only copy each string once because the compiler optimizes consecutive string concatenations into a single call to `String.Concat`:

```
string mystring = "";
mystring += a + b + c; // allocate one string; copy a, b, and c
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.  A string concatenation is a string concatenation I believe.  If you are only doing a couple of concatenations (3 or 4), it's probably better to not use StringBuilder cause StringBuilder has overhead that can be slower than the concatenations.

UPDATE

Here is the test I wrote to verify this:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestString() {
        IList<string> strings = new List<string>();
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        for (int index = 0; index < 100000; index++) {
            string t = "1" + "2" + "3";
            // Keep the compiler from optimizing this away
            strings.Add(t);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("string: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        for (int index = 0; index < 100000; index++) {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.Append("1").Append("2").Append("3");
            strings.Add(b.ToString());
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

producing this output:

```
string: 1
StringBuilder: 25
```

Comment: Hmm, any way we can verify this? I wonder what the threshold is.

Comment: There *is* a difference, the string concatenations are not done the same way, and produces different number of intermittent strings. For a few shorts strings the performance difference rarely ever matters. The threshold is somewhere around 20 strings, after that using `+=` degrades quickly, as each additional concatentation about doubles the execution time. Concatenating 30 strings using `+=` takes about 1000 times as long as concatenating 20 strings.

Comment: Ok, well words from a wiser man than I :)  I knew there was a threshold, but wasn't sure where it was exactly.

Comment: Note that the statement `string t = "1" + "2" + "3";` doesn't create any strings a all. It's just copies the reference of a literal string into the variable, so you are comparing not creating strings to creating strings, which of course is *a lot* faster. ;)

Comment: huh, well I guess I should have ToString'd the index :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your example would be better with variables. The compiler will actually do this concatenation for you since these are two string literals. So in this example there will actually do all of the work and there will be no performance hit.

To give you a better answer, there is no benefit to putting them on the same line like that. The compiler will treat them the same way and do an equal number of new string creations whether each concatenation is its own line or whether they're chained.

Comment: -1 The compiler will *not* do the same number of string creations when chaining concatenations with the `+` operator. It will create a single call to `String.Concat`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you can assume the compiler or the JIT to do the appending and only allocate one string. If the constant strings are replaced with variables that are not known at compile time the `StringBuilder` should be faster because it does not allocate that many strings.

On the other hand, three strings with length = 1 does not need much allocation and might be faster than instantiating a `StringBuilder` anyway. Only the one who measure carefully will know for sure.